# Adding Product via VF and getting Pricebookid from Opportunity

Tags: soql, pricebookentry

In my viualforce page I am adding products  - I don't want to hardcode the references to the products, I want the button to pull the proper product per Opportunity.
Why does my line not work to find the proper pricebook entry?
The method:

```
public PageReference AddJuiceProduct (){

       Opportunity TheOpp = (Opportunity)sc.GetRecord();
       NewLineItem.OpportunityId=TheOpp.id;
       NewLineItem.PricebookEntryId=[select id from PricebookEntry where name =: 'Juice' and Pricebook2id=:op.Pricebook2Id].id;
        NewLineItem.Quantity=1;
       ETC code...
       insert NewLineItem;
```

If I hardcode the reference to the product the insert works. Example:

```
NewLineItem.PricebookEntryId='123456798798794654';
```

Why doesn't this query work? thanks!

```
    NewLineItem.PricebookEntryId=[select id from PricebookEntry 
                                 where name =: 'Juice' 
                                 and Pricebook2id=:op.Pricebook2Id].id;
```

Comment: What is it you do that works? It's hard to tell exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: updated to clarify

Comment: Are you sure there is actually an entry whose `Name` is `'Juice'`?

Comment: I can find the pricebook entry if I do the below in the query editor: select id, name from PricebookEntry where name = '(juice or real product name)' and pricebook2id = '(copied id from a Opportunity)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two errors in this:
First, I declared the Opportunity variable **TheOpp**

```
 Opportunity TheOpp = (Opportunity)sc.GetRecord();
```

but then in my query used **op**.pricebook2id - this compiled b/c OP was declared as a variable elsewhere.

Next, I needed to add the fields to the controller and in the GetRecord:

```
Controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'PriceBook2Id'});
```